# API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: Invalid mapping expression specified Terraform SNS integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to deploy an AWS API Gateway with Terraform and getting the following error

```
    Error: Error creating API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:************:com-service-receive-notification-inbound]
    
      on Apps/CommunicationService/api-gateway.tf line 97, in resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration_get":
      97: resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration_get" {
```

The idea is to deploy an API Gateway and integrate it with SNS, below is a snippet of my GET method and GET integration

```
    resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method_get" {
      count         = var.application_enabled ? 1 : 0
      rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_trumpic[count.index].id
      resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource_trumpic[count.index].id
      http_method   = "GET"
      authorization = "NONE"
    
      request_parameters = {
        "method.request.path.proxy"      = true
        "method.request.querystring.xml" = true
        "method.request.querystring.Message" = true
        "method.request.querystring.TopicArn" = true
        # "method.request.querystring.message"     = true
        # "method.request.querystring.PhoneNumber" = true
      }
    }
    
    resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration_get" {
      count                   = var.application_enabled ? 1 : 0
      rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_trumpic[count.index].id
      resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource_trumpic[count.index].id
      http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.method_get[count.index].http_method
      credentials             = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch[count.index].arn
      integration_http_method = "GET"
      type                    = "AWS"
      uri                     = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:sns:path//"
    
      request_parameters = {
        # "integration.request.querystring.Message"  = "method.request.querystring.message",
        # "integration.request.querystring.Subject"  = "method.request.querystring.from",
        "integration.request.querystring.Message"  = "method.request.querystring.xml"
        "integration.request.querystring.TopicArn" = "${aws_sns_topic.com-service-receive-notification-inbound[count.index].arn}"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out  everything was correct I missed '' and that was the issue.

```
"integration.request.querystring.TopicArn" = "'${aws_sns_topic.com-service-receive-notification-inbound[count.index].arn}'"
```